# How to get mm-dd-yyyy in DOS batch file?

Tags: date, batch-file, format

In a batch file I need to get a file from a folder that has today's date.

The problem is I can't get the batch date command to return the proper format.

I have this: 
echo %date:/=-%

But that always returns for example: Fri 06-20-2014

What's the proper call for just returning: 06-20-2014

Looked all over can't find.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works independent of regional date/time format:

```bat
for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime ^|find "20"') do set dt=%%I
REM dt format is now YYYYMMDDhhmmss...
set dt=%dt:~4,2%-%dt:~6,2%-%dt:~0,4%
echo %dt%
```

Comment: works too, thanks! accepting this one because it is independent.

Answer (score 8):

```
set "$date=%date:~4%"
set "$date=%$date:/=-%"
echo %$date%
```